# Comparison function not working for equal_range

Tags: c++, boost, std

I have the following piece of code, which saves structs into a boost::ptr_vector container. I am trying now to write a simple search function for this container via equal_range. I chose that function because I want a pointer to the element of the sequence (if it is found), or pointers to the lower and upper bound (if the element is not found):

```
struct COMP
{
    bool operator()(const merkle_tree_node &LHS, const std::string& query){
        return (LHS.word < query);
    }
};

std::pair<boost::ptr_vector<merkle_tree_node>::iterator,
      boost::ptr_vector<merkle_tree_node>::iterator> 
search_tree(merkle_tree vWords, std::basic_string<char> query, size_t length)
{ 
    return std::equal_range(vWords.begin(), vWords.begin()+(length-1),
         query, 
         COMP());
}
```

Which I am calling via my main function as such:

```
std::basic_string<char> QUERY = "SOMETHING";
std::pair<boost::ptr_vector<merkle_tree_node>::iterator,
          boost::ptr_vector<merkle_tree_node>::iterator> result = 
    search_tree(vWords, QUERY, vWords.size());
```

However, I am getting the following compilation error which I just can't seem to overcome:

```
    In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/algorithm:62:0,
                     from vf-merkle.cpp:3:
    /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algo.h: In instantiation of ‘std::pair<_FIter, _FIter> std::equal_range(_FIter, _FIter, const _Tp&, _Compare) [with _FIter = boost::void_ptr_iterator<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<void**, std::vector<void*, std::allocator<void*> > >, merkle_tree_node>; _Tp = std::basic_string<char>; _Compare = COMP]’:
    vf-merkle.cpp:111:10:   required from here
    /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algo.h:2668:36: error: no match for call to ‘(COMP) (const std::basic_string<char>&, merkle_tree_node&)’
        else if (__comp(__val, *__middle))
                                        ^
    vf-merkle.cpp:98:8: note: candidate is:
     struct COMP
            ^
    vf-merkle.cpp:100:7: note: bool COMP::operator()(const merkle_tree_node&, const string&)
      bool operator()(const merkle_tree_node &LHS, const std::string& query){
           ^
    vf-merkle.cpp:100:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const std::basic_string<char>’ to ‘const merkle_tree_node&’
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer, is you need to provide both overloads for different orderings of the arguments

```
struct COMP
{
    bool operator()(const merkle_tree_node &LHS, const std::string& query){
        return (LHS.word < query);
    }

   bool operator()(const std::string& query,const merkle_tree_node &RHS){
        return (query < RHS.word);
    }
};
```

You need to do this because you are calling `std::equal_range` with the third argument of type `string`, while the iterators point to `merkle_tree_node`.  This mixed comparison case requires you to provide additional overloads to handle the case where the `string` is the first argument, or when the `string` is the second argument.  For completeness, you might want to consider adding the case where it's two instances of `merkle_tree_node`.

Answer (score 0):

You call algorithm std:;equal_range passing to it std:;string as the third argument instead of an iterator, So your using of the algorithm is invalid. Read the description of std::equal_range before using it.

Comment: Could you provide more details? "template <class ForwardIterator, class T, class Compare> pair<ForwardIterator,ForwardIterator> equal_range (ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last, const T& val, Compare comp);" The official function template seems to follow what I wrote in my question.